# How to process payments for a software (activation code)?

Tags: payment

I want to sell software online and I need an easy to implement payment processing system. What I'm actually going to be selling is an activation code (one per purchase) that would activate the trial version of a product. I was about to use [this](http://www.shareit.com/publisher.html?sessionid=1819718577&random=c6747dc0e4f4eb3b4702898ebb5ff98b) one but I just found out that people without a paid email account (not hotmail or yahoo) can't process their orders, which I'm sure would discourage many, if not most, of the possible buyers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [**PayPal**](https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/product_services&nav=2.1) for a shareware program I have been selling online since 2003.  They have a number of ways you can integrate their system with your website, so that after a customer has clicked on a Buy button on your website, and then paid through PayPal (whether they have a PayPal account or not -- they can always use a credit card), then they get sent back to your site so you can give them an activation code (or download link in my case).

Since they have a number of ways to authenticate who you are beforehand (through bank accounts, credit cards etc.), I don't think they have a restriction on your email address.